# jQuery to center div on screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I was wondering if i could get a little help modifying a piece of jQuery i have that animates the position of a div on the screen. Here it is:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $(function () {
                var offset = $("#<%= pnlMessageForm.ClientID %>").offset();
                var topPadding = 15;
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                        $("#<%= pnlMessageForm.ClientID %>").stop().animate({
                            marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                        });
                    } else {
                        $("#<%= pnlMessageForm.ClientID %>").stop().animate({
                            marginTop: 0
                        });
                    };
                });
            });
        })($telerik.$);
    </script>
```

It works great, except when i am scrolling already down the page a bit. It only adjusts its position when a scroll is performed. I need it to start out in the center... Is there a easy modification here that someone could show me that would accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically trigger the scroll event after binding it.

This can be done using the shotcut method [.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) or the [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    ...
}).trigger('scroll'); // trigger the "scroll" event
```

or

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    ...
}).scroll(); // trigger the "scroll" event
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/zYsBC/)**

Comment: I've set up a demo with what I though was what you had as you did not provided any markup nor styling.